# Pass data between two different angular applications

Tags: angular

I am working on a project in which I have two angular 7 applications. I have to redirect from one application to the other one and vice versa and to send hidden data as well (I can't send the data in the url). How can I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: If the applications are spawned inside an iframe, use [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). Else use database as a common ground for data handling

Comment: I am not using iframe. is it possible to use the local storage? The 2 applications will be deployed on the same server.

Comment: I have read that it is not possible to send post requests to an angular application since the post requests are processed on the server side (I hope I understood well)

Answer (score 0):

You should maintain a data layer in any format,as simple as a node serve hosting a single end point which serves up a json file where you can send and update data to/from . If you want a proper data management system go ahead and store it in a data source such as SQL,mongo instances

Comment: The 2 angular applications communicate with a REST back-end. What I want to send between the 2 angular applications are the credentials of a user. For example, a user logs into the first application, and then after pressing a button he is redirected to the other angular application which must receive some data and the credentials of the user. From the second application, the user can go back to the first application and must authenticate there...so the second application must send back the credentials for checking.

Comment: Then you have a back-end server which can have an authenticate end point which application 1 can hit and save the success response in a JSON object locally at the server , the application 2 will read this object when a specific end point(REST end point ) is hit by it . @Cris